# Fiddler formatting request body for POST requests w/ array URL arguments

Tags: php, http, fiddler

Say you submitted the form and you have in the Request Body:

`data[first]=johnny&data[last]=appleseed`

The normal POST request works fine from the web, but when submitted from Fiddler the PHP complains that 'data' is not an array.

I'm not sure how to format the request body such that 'data' gets recognized as an array.

Yes I'm using `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Thanks

Comment: you could monitor the browser traffic with fiddler and then drag and drop your request into the request builder, and you will have everything in front of you

Comment: do a `var_dump($_POST)`, then, and see what php's actually receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, wasn't encoding the request body properly (i.e. wasn't using %5B for '[' and %5D for ']')